# Tkinter NameError only when running script from shell

Tags: python, tkinter, python-idle, nameerror, filedialog

I've got a Tkinter Python program, a reduced version of which can be found below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

When I run this script from IDLE, I do not get any errors.

However, when run from PowerShell, using  `python myscript.py` I get

```
NameError: could not find name 'filedialog'
```

Windows 10 x64 on a mid-2012 MacBook Pro

Comment: My answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806673/importing-from-a-package-in-idle-vs-shell/38808437#38808437 described how to fix existing IDLE releases so they give the proper error.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Thanks for fixing this!  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDLE is probably importing it already, but in general since `filedialog` is a `tkinter` module it won't get imported with the bare:

```
from tkinter import *
```

Include an extra:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: Why would the filedialog module not be included in the *?

Comment: Same as `ttk` (that you're already including separately), it's a module.

Comment: This is a known IDLE bug in idlelib.run.  https://bugs.python.org/issue25507  The solution in all cases is to add the missing import, as Feneric said.  I hope to do the needed refactoring before 3.6, but must add tests first to avoid introducing new, and perhaps worse, bugs.

Comment: The Q&A persuaded me to finish the issue. Starting  with 3.5.3 and 3.6.0a4, "from tkinter import *; filedialog' will raise the appropriate NameError when run by IDLE.